# Mininet Ping Packets not visible in floodlight controller

Tags: mininet, openflow, sdn

I have set up a floodlight controller in eclipse and I have overriden

`net.floodlightcontroller.core.IListener.Command receive( IOFSwitch sw, OFMessage msg, FloodlightContext cntx)`

method in my module. I am running mininet with minimal topology. My controller is able to accept connection from mininet and I am able to see my sysouts in receive method in controller log. When I issue 'pingall' command no packets are dropped. But, I don't see anything in controller log.

Are the packets bypassing controller? Is there a way to make sure every ping packet goes through controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should implement `IOFMessageListener` and also this line in the startup function:

```
public void startUp(FloodlightModuleContext context) {
    floodlightProvider.addOFMessageListener(OFType.PACKET_IN, this);
```